# $.get() method is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have "admin_panel.php" and "admin_menu.js" file in same folder:admin.

```js
/*admin_menu.js*/
function get_data(catId) {
    $("#category_select").live("click", function() {
      $.get("admin_panel.php?title=category", {
        'catid': catId
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--admin_panel.php?title=category-->
<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'catid'])) $catid=$_GET[ 'catid']; ?>
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5px" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr align="center">
    <th>sr. no.</th>
    <th>category id</th>
    <th>category</th>
    <th>main category id</th>
    <th>select</th>
  </tr>
  <?php $query="select * from category" ; $q=m ysqli_query($con, $query); $index=1; while($result=m ysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <?=$index?>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <?=$result[ 'catid']?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?=$result[ 'category']?>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <?=$result[ 'main_catid']?>
    </td>
    <td><span id="category_select" onclick="get_data(<?=$result['catid']?>)">select</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php $index++; } ?>
</table>
```

when I click on the span I do not get 'catid' in 'admin_panel.php?title=category' page. when i remove jquery 'live' function problem is still there. Please give me a solution

Comment: Look at your console. You may be getting an error about `.live`. If so, you need to use `.on`. --- `.live` is deprecated and deleted from newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: but i have tested '.live', it is working.

Comment: then check for errors on the php side with error reporting and possibly the query

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading this correctly, when you press the span you only define the onclick listener and not triggering it. you should change the method to be:

```
function get_data(catId){
    $.get( "admin_panel.php?title=category", { 'catid': catId });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
function get_data(catId){
$("body").on("click","#category_select", function() {
    $.get( "admin_panel.php?title=category", { 'catid': catId });
});
```

Comment: still not getting

Comment: are you getting any error on the console.

Comment: no error. it is tested.

Comment: data base connectivity done ... only some part of code is given here

Comment: on console means ?

Comment: If you are on Chrome Browser:

Comment: Right Click->inspect->console(will be second option)

Comment: chrome yes..............

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)              http://localhost:82/local_search5/mycss/tab_style.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130696/discussion-between-sudip977-and-abhishek-goyal).

Comment: have you tried the other solution?